# how is my router being modified to include WAN port-binding items for Teredo and Spotify

Tags: ports

My router's configuration app (browser-interface) has a page for Virtual Server. It has entries I did not create, at least not intentionally using the interface, for Teredo, Skype, Spotify, uTorrent.

I have two questions about this:

1) how did these entries get there in the first place?

2) I changed the IP address of the gateway from 192.168.**1**.1 to 192.168.**2**.1 because we just got FIOS internet in addition to COMCAST, intending to phase out the COMCAST in the very near future;  the FIOS router was defaulted to 192.168.1.1 so I changed my router's IP address to ...2.1   and now *some* though not all of these entries for Teredo, Skype,  Spotify, and uTorrent still show the 192.168.**1**.x IP address.  Can these "stale" addresses be deleted?

Comment: This is probably a better question for SuperUser.SE, since it's not actually related to security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several protocols exist, which allow applications running behind [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)-aware routers to configure the router to make some redirections, i.e. to allow these applications to be contacted from the outside. See e.g. [IGD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol) and [NAT-PMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_Port_Mapping_Protocol). Without such specific protocols, applications which want to do direct client-to-client communications (e.g. Skype) need to resort to cruder tools like [UDP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching).

Thus, your entries were added automatically, on behalf of the applications which asked for them. How to remove stale entries is entirely device-dependent. Simply rebooting your router might do the trick; or not.

**From a security point of view**, this highlights the fact that NAT is *not* totally equivalent to a firewall which blocks incoming connections. Applications which run on the machines behind the NAT and intent on doing some server-type actions can still do them.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Pornin for the lucid and informative answer.